# inpout32.dll missing Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, dll, port, parallel-port

In my project I need to access the parellel port, to do that I wand to use the library inpout32.dll. So far I copied this dll in the folder "system32" and I followed this example http://www.qtfr.org/viewtopic.php?id=7770

My problems are :

- I can't use the type inpfuncPtr and oupfuncPtr because it's not declared
- To resolve the first issus I thought that maybe the library was not added to the project. So I test just the part of the code to load it. But this time it saids that my library is missing. "error: inpout32.dll: No such file or directory"

  ```
  #include <QCoreApplication>
  #include <QLibrary>
  #include <QFile>
  #include <QString>
  #include <QtDebug>

  #include <windows.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {

  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  HINSTANCE hLib;

  int Size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "inpout32.dll", -1, NULL, 0);
  LPWSTR wUnicode = new WCHAR[Size];
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "inpout32.dll", -1, wUnicode, Size);

  hLib = LoadLibrary(wUnicode);

  return a.exec();
  }
  ```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You question is unclear. For example, you don't say what fails, and how it fails.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. When I compile the code I have this error "error: inpout32.dll: No such file or directory" .

Comment: How did you 'have' it? Did the computer speak with human voice and tell it to you, or what?

Comment: This error is shown within the compiler output on Qt.

Comment: The "Compile Output" pane? As in, not the "Application Output" pane, which shows the running application's output, not the compiler's output?

Comment: Yes it's the Compile Output pane, I don't have a running application yet because of this error.

Comment: Try putting the dll in the same dir as the executable, this is the first path searched according to the documentation for LoadLibrary

Comment: He says his program doesn't compile at all because of a missing dll (not lib or h file).

Comment: I already tried to put the dll in the same dir but it was still not working

Comment: First of all, is it really inpout32.dll or is it input32.dll. Second you should not just put random libs in your system32-folder, better keep them at your local development directory. Third dll's are not needed for compilation but the header files should be included. Did you somewhere make a call like: ``#include <inpout32.dll>``?